# Angular instance of global service using a repeated component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a service which has been declared in the app.module.ts like:

```
import { SelectGroup } from './services/select-form.service';
providers: [
  SelectGroup,
],
```

So, I have a component which is used in a page more than once.This is the component:

```
import { SelectGroup } from './../../../../../app/services/select-form.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'cmp-select-form',
  templateUrl: 'select-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-form.component.scss'],
})

export class SelectComponent extends FormBaseCmp implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor(private element: ElementRef, private selectGroupService: SelectGroup) {
}
```

In theory, in this way it should instance the service once, but everytime I create a select-form in a page create a new instance of the service and I need to share the same data between them. How I have to do to get only one instance of the service?

Comment: *it should instance the service once* - and it does in the code you've posted. And it will be so, unless you specified it in component `providers`. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem if it persists.

Comment: Fixed! I've been checking the code and there was a `this.selectGroupService = new SelectGroup();` and here was the problem